# dat.gui in three.js not applying changes

Tags: three.js, dat.gui

I am learning three.js. But when I try to use the dat.gui library, no change is applied to the light. I have given the codes in the link.

```
   gui.add(spotLight, 'penumbra', 0, 1).step(0.01);
    gui.add(spotLight, 'intensity', 0, 10).step(1);
    gui.add(spotLight, 'distance', 0, 10).step(1);
    gui.add(spotLight, 'decay', 0, 10).step(1);
    gui.add(spotLight, 'power', 0, 10).step(1);
    gui.add(spotLight.position, 'x', 0, 10).step(1);
    gui.add(spotLight.position, 'y', 0, 10).step(1);
    gui.add(spotLight.position, 'z', 0, 10).step(1);
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tf84pk76/)

I created spotlight and tried to change the properties of this spotlight in real time with gui but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering the scene just once so changing the light won't be visible on the canvas. This issue can be solved in two ways:

- Use an animation loop.
- Use the `onChange()` callback of `dat.gui` and call the `render()` method.

I've updated your fiddle with the second approach: https://jsfiddle.net/ertpdgvn/

BTW: `dat.gui` is not used by `three.js` anymore. The project uses [lil-gui](https://github.com/georgealways/lil-gui) now which has a similar API.